# Saving datetime and different time from a radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am currently making a cinema booking system. When saving current date to the database I save the current date with this code:

```
scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booking_date", DateTime.Now);
```

Which works fine, until I enter a time for the movie, which I choose from radio buttons that have the values 10:00, 14:00, etc

The radio button group is named rbtime and I save it to database here:

```
scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@performance_time", rbtime.SelectedValue);
```

When selected it shows the current time, and booking time is set to 1900/01/01. However when I comment out:

```
scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booking_date", DateTime.Now);
```

it saves the selected time from the radio buttons fine.

I'm saving current date to date and the selected time to time(7) datatypes.
Do any of you know how to save current date and a different time without them conflicting like this?

Sql statement is here:

```
string movie_ID = string.Empty;
string movie_Name = string.Empty;
string movie_certification = string.Empty;
string showing_ID = string.Empty;
string venue_name = string.Empty;
string UserId = string.Empty;
string UserName = string.Empty;
string seat_cat= this.rbseat_cat.SelectedItem.Text; 
string performance_date = string.Empty;
string performance_time = string.Empty;
string booking_date = string.Empty;
string venue_ID = string.Empty;
int GVCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;

booking_date =  DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

foreach (GridViewRow GVRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    UserId = GVRow.Cells[0].Text;
    UserName = GVRow.Cells[1].Text;
    venue_ID = GVRow.Cells[2].Text;
    venue_name = GVRow.Cells[3].Text;
    showing_ID = GVRow.Cells[4].Text;
    movie_ID = GVRow.Cells[5].Text;
    movie_Name = GVRow.Cells[6].Text;
    movie_certification = GVRow.Cells[7].Text;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand();
    scm.Connection = conn;
    scm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO booking
        (user_ID, user_name, venue_ID,venue_name,showing_ID, movie_ID, movie_name, movie_cert, seat_cat, performance_date, booking_date, performance_time)  
        VALUES  
        (@UserID, @UserName, @venue_ID, @venue_name, @showing_ID, @movie_ID, @movie_Name, @movie_certification, @seat_cat,     @performance_date,@performance_time, @booking_date)";

    scm.Connection = conn;
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movie_ID", movie_ID.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movie_Name", movie_Name.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movie_certification", movie_certification.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@showing_ID", showing_ID.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@venue_ID", venue_ID.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@venue_name", venue_name.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName.ToString());
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booking_date", DateTime.Now);
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@performance_date", DateTime.Parse(DropDownListDate.SelectedItem.Text));
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@performance_time", rbtime.SelectedValue);
    scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seat_cat", rbseat_cat.SelectedValue);

    scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you combine them and store them in a single column in the database, rather than splitting them into separate columns?

Comment: because they are not related. the time is the time of the movie not the time of the booking

Comment: They shouldn't be conflicting. Show your SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert statement is out of order. You have defined the order of the variables as:

`... seat_cat, performance_date, booking_date, performance_time)`

but on the next line when you actually set your parameters you have:

`... @seat_cat, @performance_date, @performance_time, @booking_date)";`

Notice how the performance dates match up, but in place of booking date you are actually inserting performance time and vice versa.

Comment: Don't know how the hell I did that... Anyway that sorted it, thanks alot you're a lifesaver!